# Is there a simple explanation to why the line of best fit passes through $\bar x$ and $\bar y$?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Is there a clear explanation someone can give an undergrad as to why a line of best fit in a linear model must always pass through a point/coordinate indicating the mean of the $x$ and $y$ values ($\bar{x}$, $\bar{y}$) and why the sums of the least squares must equal $0$?

It is a hard concept I have not been able to grasp…

Thank you.

Comment: By "the sums of the least squares" do you mean the sum of the residuals?

Comment: Can I use derivatives in my explanation?

Comment: Yes I mean sum of residuals and derivatives are more than welcome Andrei

Answer (score 4):

You need a bit of undergraduate calculus to understand this.

Let $y=mx+b$ denote the equation of the line which minimizes

$$ S=\sum_{k=1}^n[y_k-(mx_k+b)]^2$$

Then S is a second-degree polynomial in two variables $m$ and $b$. So the partials derivatives of $S$ with respect to both $m$ and $b$ will be zero at any extreme value, such as the minimum.

Taking $\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial b}$ we get

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}&=&-2\sum_{k=1}^n[y_k-(mx_k+b)]\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^ny_k&=&m\sum_{k=1}^nx_k+\sum_{k=1}^nb\\
\sum_{k=1}^ny_k&=&m\sum_{k=1}^nx_k+nb\\
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^ny_k&=&\frac{m}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k+b\\
\bar{y}&=&m\bar{x}+b
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the equation of the linear regression line to see that the point $(\bar x, \bar y)$ satisfies the equation.

It is not obvious and it is not quite intuitive, it is just the nature of the least square line.